# Baking Turnips But are coming out burnt or soggy

Tags: baking

I have tried baking turnips but they turn out very soggy or burnt.  Any ideas?  Below is the recipe I was using.

- Oven 350
- Turnips
- Olive oil
- Rosemary

I baked the slices on a baking sheet with the olive oil and rosemary brushed on both sides for about 30-45 minutes.

Comment: What kind of texture are you expecting?

Comment: more of a chip like. crispy.  or like a crisp, outside of the US

Comment: Have you tried drying the turnips out some (with a salt coating) before baking (or during baking, even)?

Comment: No, I haven't!  I don't have a dehydrator, so how would I dry them?  Just leave them out with salt on them?

Comment: How thick are the slices?

Comment: Placing them on a rack and thence in the fridge for a few hours will dry them out too.

Comment: I would venture a guess that the thickness is near Julienne thickness.

Comment: Julienne is about 1/8 inch or a few millimeters.  Have you noticed how potato chips are half that or less?

Comment: Sadly I don't have a machine to slice.  It's just my amateur cutting ability.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest you are going to seriously struggle, it's possible but hard. I've had similar issue's trying to make sweet potato mash.

To begin with you are going to need to run the sliced turnips under cold running for a little while (20mins) not sure why but it does help. (also helps with potato and beetroot crisps.

Instead of going in the oven full wack from the start you'll want to start low (130c) for 20-30 to help dry off excess moisture. Then remove the tray from the oven. Turn the oven up to 200c let it get to temp. Now toss the crisps in oil,  season with quite a lot of sea salt (a lot of it will fall off so don't be tight throw it on) and  return the crisps to the oven. Check ever 5min turning each time until they start to colour. Initially while still warm they will still be a little soft but once they cool down they will start to crisp up.

Also worth considering is a product from msk called 'crisp film' which really gives this kind of thing that "walkers" style crunch.

Side note: I think I used the word crisp far too many times ...

Comment: Very thankful for this!  I'll do my best to try it out tonight.  Thank you Doug!